# Хорошая практика в подгрузке списка

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть метод который возвращает некоторое количество записей и общее их число в json, ответ примерно выглядит так:

```
{
    hits:100
    ...тут идут переданные записи
}
```

В параметрах запроса можно указать два параметра limit - число передаваемых записей и page сдвиг по записям на limit.
Записей может быть около 1000 и грузить их сразу все очевидно нельзя. Я сделал некоторое подобие автоматической подгрузки, работает оно примерно так:

1. Делается превый запрос с page 0 и limit 50
2. После разбора ответа смотрим hits и делаем запрос еще раз.
3. Повторять до достижения цели

Мне не нравится несколько моментов

1. Грузятся сразу все элементы
2. При обновлении списка RecyclerView перескакивает на первый элемент

Как лучше поступить с этими двумя проблемами?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    //  1. У вас на экране не все, только то что видите, все остальные элементы дестроятся, как только "ушли" за пределы экрана.


  //  Для сохранения текущей позиции запомните высоту списка до //обновления, к примеру через `OnScrollListener`:



    //    private int mScrollY;
    //            private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener mScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
   //                 @Override
   //                 public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    //                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    //                    mScrollY += dy;
    //                    }

    //            }; 

   // После обновления данных вызывайте программно скролл

      //  mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, mStateScrollY);
```

**UPDATE** 
Со временем было вычитано более правильное решение. Добавьте метод в ваш адаптер для RecyclerView

```
public void setData(List<String> data) {
        mStringData.addAll(data); // ваша коллекция данных для адаптера
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - data.size());
    }
```

Как следствие без велосипедов адаптер добавит еще элементы в конец списка, без каких либо подергиваний или запоминании позиции скролла на экране.